# Getting symbol not found for symbols like Assert for junit test cases while building a project in jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, junit, junit5

I have Junit test cases in my maven spring boot project. While building the project, the junit symbols are not found such as Before, Assert. What can be the issue?

Some of the logs are as below,

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/svn repo/delivery-management- 
   service/src/test/java/com/poc/delivery/DeliveryControllerNewTest.java:[4,24] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Assert
      location: package org.junit
[ERROR] /C:/svn repo/delivery-management- 
    service/src/test/java/com/poc/delivery/DeliveryControllerNewTest.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class Before
    location: package org.junit
```

Comment: Did you check if you have junit 4 dependency in your pom.xml. can you share your pom.xml file ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you did not declare import for `Assert` and `Before` static method

```
    import org.junit.Assert;
    ... 
    Assert.assertEquals(...)
```

and

```
    import org.junit.Before;
```

you could also run `mvn install` to make sure that all dependencies was download locally